# Gibbon / Mailchimp Signup Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, email, mailchimp, gibbon

Having some trouble creating a simple signup form for a mailchimp list. Can't figure out why when they email passes through, it doesn't pass over to mailchimp.. thoughts? I'm sure I missed a step here.

index.html.erb (Form)

```
<%= form_tag('/welcome/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe",) do -%>
<%= email_field(:email, :address, {id: "email", placeholder: "email address"}) %>
<%= submit_tag("Join!") %>
<% end %>
```

Gibbon.rb (Initializer)

```
Gibbon::API.api_key = "Secret API Key"
Gibbon::API.timeout = 15
Gibbon::API.throws_exceptions = false
```

Welcome.rb (Model)

```
def subscribe

@list_id = "Secret List ID"
gb = Gibbon::API.new

gb.lists.subscribe({
  :id => @list_id,
  :email => {:email => params[:email][:address]}
  })
end
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root 'welcome#index'
post 'welcome/subscribe' => 'welcome#subscribe'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users are probably being added as pending, requiring them to opt-in to be fully subscribed. You'll want to pass the `double_opt_in: false` parameter to your subscribe call.

Comment: Thanks! Should've noticed this by checking the email I was test registering... 7 "can you please confirm" emails sitting there answering this question for me -_-. Appreciate the help!